# Confused about the use of slice in javascript

Tags: javascript

I just started learning Javascript. One of the exercises is using slice. My understanding is that slice creates a shallow copy of an array, and that shallow copy, will contain elements from the original array, as called.

```
var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Lemon", "Apple", "Mango"];
var citrus = fruits.slice(1, 3);
console.log(citrus);
```

And I get:

```
Orange, Lemon
```

fruits[1] is Orange
fruits[3] is Apple

I am expecting

```
Orange, Apple
```

What am I missing?

Comment: [First paragraph in the MDN documentation.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)

Comment: It's a range of the array, starting from 1 (inclusive) to 3 (exclusive).

Comment: Not specific elements of the array.

Comment: @Pointy I did read it, but now reading it again, it's clearer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The slice() method selects the elements starting at the given start argument, and ends at, but does not include, the given end argument.

You were even on the document page
[https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_slice_array.asp#:~:text=The%20slice()%20method%20returns,array%20will%20not%20be%20changed](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_slice_array.asp#:%7E:text=The%20slice()%20method%20returns,array%20will%20not%20be%20changed).

Answer (score 0):

the syntax for slice():

```
slice(start)
slice(start, end)
```

Returns elements from the 'start' index up until the 'end' index (not including the 'end' index)

Answer (score 0):

Read this:

### **Array.prototype.slice()**

**Parameters**

> ***start*** **Optional**
>
> Zero-based index at which to start extraction.
>
> A negative index can be used, indicating an offset from the end of the
> sequence. slice(-2) extracts the last two elements in the sequence.
>
> If start is undefined, slice starts from the index 0.
>
> If start is greater than the index range of the sequence, an empty
> array is returned.

> ***end*** **Optional**
>
> Zero-based index before which to end extraction. slice extracts up to
> but not including end. For example, slice(1,4) extracts the second
> element through the fourth element (elements indexed 1, 2, and 3).
>
> A negative index can be used, indicating an offset from the end of the
> sequence. slice(2,-1) extracts the third element through the
> second-to-last element in the sequence.
>
> If end is omitted, slice extracts through the end of the sequence
> (arr.length).
>
> If end is greater than the length of the sequence, slice extracts
> through to the end of the sequence (arr.length).

**Source**: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice#parameters

Answer (score 0):

The slice method returns a part of the array between two indexes (end index not included)
This means that if you do something like:

```js
let arr = ['foo', 'bar', 'yin', 'yang']
console.log(arr.slice(1, 3))
```

The expected output will be `['bar', 'yin']` because you will get all the element of the array starting from index 1 to index 3 - 1.